# How to create Modal Window using React Native?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

developers!

I have tried to create a simple Modal Window with React.

But my window still not appeared!

So, my code have two parts: JS-part and CSS-part.

I used "Modal" keyword, constructor and render(). All my code was written in CodePen area, so I'm able to see the result. But still something missing. What is it?

It will be mobile application. So, should I use keyword "Native" somewhere?

```js
import "./modal.scss";

class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return !I.is(this.props.data, nextProps.data);
  }

  render() {
    let isOpen = this.props.data.get("isOpen");
    return (
      <div className={`flex middle center modal ${isOpen ? "open" : ""}`}>
      {isOpen ?
        (<div className={`row modal-content ${this.props.size || ""}`}>
          <div className="col-12 middle modal-title">{this.props.title}</div>
          <div className="col-12 modal-body">
            {this.props.body}
          </div>
          <div className="col-12 middle modal-footer">{this.props.footer}</div>
        </div>) : null
      }
      </div>);
  }
}

export default Modal;
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);

  .modal-content {
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 80%;
    height: 80%;

    .modal-title {
      padding: 0 2.25rem;
      height: 5rem;
      max-height: 5rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
    }

    .modal-body {
      height: calc(100% - 16rem);
      overflow-y: scroll;
      padding: 0 2rem;
    }

    .modal-footer {
      height: 5rem;
      max-height: 5rem;
      padding: 0 2.25rem;
    }
  }
}
```

See also a fragment from CodePen: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlURm.jpg)

Comment: This doesn't seems to be related to React Native

Comment: how to make it as React Native?

Comment: This link should help you then: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal

Comment: Btw, you can't just copy past react code to create a React Native app (maybe some tools exist but I can't help you with those)

Answer (score 0):

```
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal isVisible={true}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>I am the modal content!</Text>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

See also https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal

Comment: this one is true. But I didn't get a visible Modal Window in my CodePen tool. Something is missing. (screenshot attached)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is make a mobile application. The best way to do that would be to use React `React Native` instead of `React`

Check this out:

> https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

Once you're started showing a modal on a screen is quite simple.

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal#docsNav

If this is your first time, it would be best to follow the getting started guide on React Native's website. Its helpful. There are no divs, but inLine styling can still be used.

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Hope this helps